# Onde e quando decidir qual classe concreta (que implementa determinada interface) deverá ser instanciada?

Tags: c#, interface, injeção-de-dependência

Ok, este é o problema clássico a ser resolvido com uso de interfaces, certo?  Vamos ao exemplo:

Tenho um DLL que será utilizada por diferentes empresas, cada uma com seu banco e seu cadastro de Pessoa, quero prover uma interface para que as diferentes empresas implementem seus DAO's de Pessoa, exemplo:

Interface que vou prover para que cada empresa implemente seu DAO

```
interface IDAOPessoa
{
    Pessoa ObterPessoa(string nome);
}
```

A Empresa1 provavelmente desenvolverá algo assim

```
public class DAOPessoaEmpresa1 : IDAOPessoa
{
    public Pessoa ObterPessoa(string nome)
    {
        // Select * from TBL_PESSOA WHERE nome = @nome
    }
}
```

A Empresa 2, provavelmente desenvolverá algo assim

```
public class DAOPessoaEmpresa2 : IDAOPessoa
{
    public Pessoa ObterPessoa(string nome)
    {
        // Select * from PESSOA WHERE NM_PESSOA = @nome
    }
}
```

Quando cada empresa instancia a DLL onde essas classes estão, a empresa passa um parâmetro para a DLL para identificar qual empresa esta usando a DLL naquele momento. Então, o código óbvio para decidir qual DAO instanciar seria algo assim:

```
public class InicioDLL
{
    public IDAOPessoa daoPessoa { get; set; }
    public InicioDLL(string nomeEmpresa)
    {
        switch (nomeEmpresa)
        {
            case "Empresa1":
                daoPessoa = new DAOPessoaEmpresa1();
                break;
            case "Empresa2":
                daoPessoa = new DAOPessoaEmpresa2();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Claro que este código não é sustentável nem manutenível pois eu teria que fazer isso toda vez que precisasse de de um IDAOPessoa (ou criar uma fábrica pra isso).

Dai vem as perguntas:

1. Onde e como decidir qual DAO de Pessoa Concreta instanciar?
2. Um framework de DI poderia ser útil nestes casos? Se sim, pode dar um exemplo?

Comment: Dica: Você precisar criar duas interface pra cada Dal e não liga direto nessa.

Comment: Salvo eu ter entendido algo errado pra mim isto provavelmente nem deveria ser resolvido desta forma. Deveria ter uma classe só com o método delegado para cada empresa. Toda vez que alguém usa reflexão um panda morre. Em alguns casos o `switch` pode sim ser boa solução, ou então poderia ter um sistema de registro das classes em um *array*, em uma variação do que se costuma fazer com Observable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode implementar uma solução composta de duas partes: Carga dinâmica de *assemblies* via *Reflection*, e resolução de instância.

---

### Carga de Assemblies via *Reflection*

Uma vez compiladas as classes geradas pelo cliente podem ser arbitrariamente disponibilizadas e carregadas via *reflection*, fazendo com que estas sejam disponibilizadas durante *runtime* no *AppDomain* atual.

No *bootstrap* da sua aplicação carregue o *assembly* criado pelo cliente:

```
System.Reflection.Assembly
    .LoadFrom("C:\solucao\DefinicoesDeCliente.dll");
```

---

### Resolução de instância

Sua aplicação foi inicializada corretamente, o *assembly* do cliente foi carregado, e agora você precisa instanciar a classe que implementa `IDAOPessoa` criada por ele.

Primeiro vamos determinar o tipo a ser instanciado:

```
Type ti = typeof(IDAOPessoa);

Type alvo = null;

foreach (Assembly asm in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()) {
    foreach (Type t in asm.GetTypes()) {
        if (ti.IsAssignableFrom(t)) {
            alvo = t; // Agora sabemos o tipo utilizado pelo cliente.
        }
    }
}
```

<sup>(Versão modificada de https://stackoverflow.com/a/26745/1845714)</sup>

De posse do tipo podemos agora criar uma instância da classe:

```
IDAOPessoa instanciaDao = 
    (IDAOPessoa)System.Activator.CreateInstance(alvo);
```

Você agora pode chamar métodos de `instanciaDao`:

```
var pessoa = instanciaDao.ObterPessoa("Ewerton");
```

Comment: Vejam, ele vive!

Comment: @Bacco "Antigos espirítos do mal, transformem essa forma decadente em OnoSendai-Ra, o de vida eterna!"